# All Scheduled Jobs are running even though node id's are mentioned

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, terracotta

I have two jobs configured. And i have mentioned node id of job groups.
My requirement is to run particular jobs on particular node mentioned.
But when i start my application all jobs are executed even though i mention node Id in properties file.

Please check below code. I am using Quartz with Spring boot.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terracotta.toolkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.terracotta.quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-terracotta-ee</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

**FirstJob**

```
public class FirstJob implements Job, Serializable {


    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("In First Job Execution....");
        JobKey jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
        JobDataMap data = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    }
```

**SecondJob**

```
public class SecondJob implements Job, Serializable {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("In Second Job Execution....");
        JobKey jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
        JobDataMap data = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    }
}
```

**ScheduleConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerConfig.class);

@Bean
public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
}


@Bean
public Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource,JobFactory jobFactory)throws Exception{
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
    scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey("FirstJob", "firstTriggers");
    CronTrigger trigger = (CronTrigger) scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);

    JobDetail jobDetail = localJob(newJob(FirstJob.class).withIdentity("FirstJob", "firstJobs")
            .withDescription("i am first job").storeDurably(true).build())
            .where(node().is(partOfNodeGroup("firstJobs"))).build();

    FirstJob job = new FirstJob();
    jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("firstJob", job);

    CronScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?");
    trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("FirstJob", "firstTriggers")
            .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder).build();
    System.out.println("Successfully configured First Job");
    //Second Job

    TriggerKey triggerKey1 = TriggerKey.triggerKey("SecondJob", "secondTriggers");
    CronTrigger trigger1 = (CronTrigger) scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey1);

    JobDetail jobDetail1 = localJob(newJob(SecondJob.class).withIdentity("SecondJob", "secondJobs")
            .withDescription("i am second job").storeDurably(true).build())
            .where(node().is(partOfNodeGroup("secondJobs"))).build();

    SecondJob secondJob = new SecondJob();
    jobDetail1.getJobDataMap().put("secondJob", job);
    CronScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder1 = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/17 * * * * ?");
    trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SecondJob", "secondTriggers")
            .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder1).build();
    System.out.println("Successfully configured Second Job");

    System.out.println("Starting Schedulers....");
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail1, trigger1);

    scheduler.start();
    return scheduler;
}

@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartzLocality.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
}
```

**application properties**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:db/quartz_tables_mysql.sql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

**quartz.properties**

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=springboot-quartz
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=node1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass= 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 0
```

**quartzLocality.properties**

```
org.quartz.locality.nodeGroup.firstJobs = node0
#org.quartz.locality.nodeGroup.secondJobs = node1

org.quartz.locality.nodeGroup.allNodes = node0,node1

org.quartz.locality.nodeGroup.firstJobs.triggerGroups = firstTriggers
org.quartz.locality.nodeGroup.secondJobs.triggerGroups = secondTriggers
```

**edit:Console log**

First i get this

```
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Next i get this in same execution..

```
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered
```

Comment: can you give us the console messages you are getting. I did a quick test and obviously because I don't have a cluster setup... I see the following: `org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler 
 quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.`  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos I have added console details please check. And first time what ever configuration i give its working, next the default properties of quartz is loading. Might this be the issue...?

Comment: I see the same issue I had. 
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered

Comment: But my properties file says clustered=true and jdbcJobStore...? right

Comment: Maybe you are missing something like: org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass . I see 2-3 properties that are missing: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html

Comment: I have added `org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass= 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate` in quartz.properties ....

Comment: Could you double check with this: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html ? I see also `org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = SOMETHING`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179520/discussion-between-hema-and-menelaos-bakopoulos).

Answer (score 1):

### intro :

Are you sure that you are running in clustered mode correctly?

Is your spring boot configuration and project configured correctly in relation to clustering?

In my own tests ( when I don't have clustering enabled), I see the following indications:

> Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not
>   support persistence. and is not clustered.
>
> 2018-09-05 13:35:03.433  INFO 9096 --- [           main]
>   org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler
>   quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.

And ofcourse the jobs start immediately on the local machine.

Maybe your configuration needs tweeking in relation to spring boot and clustering. For example: https://medium.com/@Hronom/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-in-cluster-mode-457f4535104d

### Update :

Based  on your logs, I see the same problem:

`Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered`

Can you try a tutorial such as this one, in order to add clustering support:

- https://medium.com/@Hronom/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-in-cluster-mode-457f4535104d
- http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am setting it hard coding in SchedulerConfig. I am not using that in config. As per cron expression both jobs are working at proper intervals.But i need to run Jobs based on nodeId mentioned